# CAS 4.2 get LDAP attributes

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

I am using the below configuration to successfully get LDAP attribute values and I could see those values in log file.

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
              p:principalIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
              c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
            <property name="principalAttributeMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="displayName" value="simpleName" />
                    <entry key="mail" value="email" />
                    <entry key="memberOf" value="membership" />
                </map>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

Now how can I send these attributes to client?

This is the default attributeRepository in my deployerConfigContext.xml:

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.NamedStubPersonAttributeDao"
          p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />

 <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
    <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
    <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
    <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
    <entry>
        <key><value>memberOf</value></key>
        <list>
            <value>faculty</value>
            <value>staff</value>
            <value>org</value>
        </list>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

Is there a way to populate attributeRepository with principalAttributeMap?

Its throwing exception when I remove attributeRepository from deployerConfigContext.xml.

As per this document https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html, LdapAuthenticationHandler is capable of resolving and retrieving principal attributes independently without the need for extra principal resolver machinery. If so, how can we return those attributes to clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this documentation https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html,

If you do decide to let the authentication handler retrieve attributes instead of a separate principal resolver, you will need to ensure the linked resolver is made inactive:

```
<util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
   ...
   <entry key-ref="ldapAuthenticationHandler" value="#{null}" />
</util:map>
```

After making this change, it started working.